# How to create automatic e mail notification when contacting someone via a web pages forum

Tags: velo

we do have a web page with an integrated Forum.
It´s helping to conect people with each other. We try to figure out how we could make a person who is beeing contacted, send an automatic e mail notification that she was contacted.
Normally we also work with Geolocalizacion, where i can find the different persons and where they are located.
Any ideas about this e mauil notification system in case somebody is writing to somebody of the map in this forum ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://support.wix.com/en/article/customizing-notifications-in-wix-forum

Always use a website's documentation site for asking questions or reading articles to get answers. They have tutorials for almost anything on their site.

You just have to tell them to enable it. You can't have it automatically email. Wix doesn't allow that.